# loading header first, before waiting to load main content in angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loader

I have a standard website, with layout as below (excuse my great artistic skills!))

```
|-------------------|
|   HEADER          |
|___________________|

|------||-----------|
| side ||  Main     |
| bar  ||  Content  |
|      ||           |
|------||------------
```

I am using Angular UI-router for routing and states.  This is using resolvers to load data for particular states. If I navigate to a state, first all the data is loaded, and then all of the 3 main components appear at once.  Usually, the header / side bar are very quick to load, and the main content takes a bit more time.

Is it possible to somehow show them appearing in order:

1. Header
2. Sidebar
3. Main Content

Also, preferably, the main-content would also include a loader.  My first idea was to put code in the controller rather than as resolver, but I think that the resolver-way is much more elegant.

Comment: are you using different controllers for header, sidebar and content?

Comment: Yes, I am using different controllers and directives for every components like the header, sidebar, content.  All data is currently being loaded in ui-router resolvers, and the data loads all at once. The issue is how to make it such that the header shows first, then the other data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular defer, for create promises and organize your code, with angular defer you can call methods after showing something.

[you can see the documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

for example:

```
var showheader=function()
{
  var defer=$q.defer();
     //do your stuff
     //show your header
  defer.resolve();
  return defer.promise;
}
showheader().then(function(){
    //show your main and sidebar  
});
```

Comment: I don't think this has to do with what I'm talking about. Resolvers already use promises, so I'm using defer / promises already.

Comment: you can use ng-include, you will be able to load first one module and then an other one. if inside a module you call an other one.